# can't compile vb wsdl stub in mono

Tags: vb.net, mono, wsdl

I'm testing Mono on OSX 10.9. This guide shows howto use web services: http://www.mono-project.com/Web_Services_%28Visual_Basic%29 but I can't compile the code genereaded by wdsl.

Generate VB stub:

```
gizurmaca00510e:web-service jonas$ wsdl http://dic.googlecode.com/files/GoogleSearch.wsdl-language:vb
Web Services Description Language Utility
Mono Framework v4.0.30319.17020

There were some warnings while generating the code:

  http://dic.googlecode.com/files/GoogleSearch.wsdl
- This web reference does not conform to WS-I Basic Profile v1.1
    R2706: A wsdl:binding in a DESCRIPTION MUST use the value of "literal"
    for the use attribute in all soapbind:body, soapbind:fault,
    soapbind:header and soapbind:headerfault elements
      * Binding 'GoogleSearchBinding', in Service Description
        'urn:GoogleSearch'
    R2209: A wsdl:binding in a DESCRIPTION SHOULD bind every wsdl:part of a
    wsdl:message in the wsdl:portType to which it refers to one of
    soapbind:body, soapbind:header, soapbind:fault  or soapbind:headerfault
      * Binding 'GoogleSearchBinding', in Service Description
        'urn:GoogleSearch'
    R2102: A QName reference to a Schema component in a DESCRIPTION MUST
    use the namespace defined in the targetNamespace attribute on the
    xsd:schema element, or to a namespace defined in the namespace
    attribute on an xsd:import element within the xsd:schema element
      * XmlSchemaComplexContentRestriction in Schema Schema
        'urn:GoogleSearch', in Service Description 'urn:GoogleSearch'
      * XmlSchemaAttribute in Schema Schema 'urn:GoogleSearch', in Service
        Description 'urn:GoogleSearch'
      * XmlSchemaComplexContentRestriction in Schema Schema
        'urn:GoogleSearch', in Service Description 'urn:GoogleSearch'
      * XmlSchemaAttribute in Schema Schema 'urn:GoogleSearch', in Service
        Description 'urn:GoogleSearch'
    R2110: In a DESCRIPTION, array declarations MUST NOT extend or restrict
    the soapenc:Array type
      * XmlSchemaComplexContentRestriction in Schema Schema
        'urn:GoogleSearch', in Service Description 'urn:GoogleSearch'
      * XmlSchemaComplexContentRestriction in Schema Schema
        'urn:GoogleSearch', in Service Description 'urn:GoogleSearch'
    R2111: In a DESCRIPTION, array declarations MUST NOT use wsdl:arrayType
    attribute in the type declaration
      * XmlSchemaAttribute in Schema Schema 'urn:GoogleSearch', in Service
        Description 'urn:GoogleSearch'
      * XmlSchemaAttribute in Schema Schema 'urn:GoogleSearch', in Service
        Description 'urn:GoogleSearch'

Writing file 'GoogleSearchService.vb'
```

Compiling the code:

```
gizurmaca00510e:web-service jonas$ vbnc /target:library GoogleSearchService.vb -r:System.Web.Services.dll,System.Xml.dll
Visual Basic.Net Compiler version 0.0.0.5943 (Mono 3.0 - xamarin/9fc7213)
Copyright (C) 2004-2010 Rolf Bjarne Kvinge. All rights reserved.

/Users/jonas/git/colmsjo/develvm/excel_sandbox/mono/web-service/GoogleSearchService.vb (66,12) : error VBNC30455: Argument not specified for parameter 'arg' of 'Private Sub OndoGetCachedPageCompleted(arg As Object)'.
/Users/jonas/git/colmsjo/develvm/excel_sandbox/mono/web-service/GoogleSearchService.vb (66,12) : error VBNC30455: Argument not specified for parameter 'arg' of 'Private Sub OndoGetCachedPageCompleted(arg As Object)'.
/Users/jonas/git/colmsjo/develvm/excel_sandbox/mono/web-service/GoogleSearchService.vb (99,12) : error VBNC30455: Argument not specified for parameter 'arg' of 'Private Sub OndoSpellingSuggestionCompleted(arg As Object)'.
/Users/jonas/git/colmsjo/develvm/excel_sandbox/mono/web-service/GoogleSearchService.vb (99,12) : error VBNC30455: Argument not specified for parameter 'arg' of 'Private Sub OndoSpellingSuggestionCompleted(arg As Object)'.
/Users/jonas/git/colmsjo/develvm/excel_sandbox/mono/web-service/GoogleSearchService.vb (132,12) : error VBNC30455: Argument not specified for parameter 'arg' of 'Private Sub OndoGoogleSearchCompleted(arg As Object)'.
/Users/jonas/git/colmsjo/develvm/excel_sandbox/mono/web-service/GoogleSearchService.vb (132,12) : error VBNC30455: Argument not specified for parameter 'arg' of 'Private Sub OndoGoogleSearchCompleted(arg As Object)'.
There were 6 errors and 0 warnings.
Compilation took 00:00:00.8969520
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a problem with wsdl not generating the `AddressOf` modifier for delegates.

You can fix this yourself by modifying the file like this:

```
Me.doGetCachedPageOperationCompleted = New System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(Me.OndoGetCachedPageCompleted)
```

to:

```
Me.doGetCachedPageOperationCompleted = New System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(AddressOf Me.OndoGetCachedPageCompleted)
```

for all three locations (note that the line number is off by one, for the example above it reported line 66, but the real line is 65).

Alternatively you can use this already fixed version: https://gist.github.com/rolfbjarne/cf950b0815f609e679c1